# featherlight.js lightbox with bootstrap-datepicker

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, featherlight.js

I am having problem with bootstrap-datepicker open within featherlight lightbox. the datepicker moving out of area and lightbox shadow effect is getting disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Late to answer this but for anyone getting here via google...

You will need to decrease the z-index of the featherlight div.  Something like:

```
  .featherlight{
    z-index:100!important;
  }
```

should do it.  Balancing the z-indexes is the key to the problem.